# Will calculating standard deviations from percentages give different results to claculating them from the raw data?

Tags: standard-deviation

I'll start off by saying I am not a mathematician, nor have I studied maths for many years, so please keep the answers simple :)

I am working with data that has a geographical context.
So assume I have data about an area 10km by 10km.  My data is split into 1km by 1mk tiles, so I have 100 rows of data.  1 row for each km square in my area.

Values in my data include the following, to name a few:

Number of buildings

Number of addresses

Number of postcodes

% ground area covered by buildings in the km square

I am creating some cloropleth maps to give an overview of the whole area.
I am symbolising the data using standard deviation so I can show which km squares are above and below the mean.

This works well for things such as building counts, so I know if a single km square is above or below the mean for the whole 100km area.

My question is, am I able to calculate the standard deviation for my % values? i.e. % ground area covered by buildings, % ground area covered by roads etc...
Will this give me a sensible result?

Or would it be best to calculate the standard deviation on the actual area covered by these features in each km tile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purpose of this answer I'll use the "% ground area covered by buildings".  Since each of your data points corresponds to $1$ km by $1$ km tiles it actually doesn't "matter" if you use percentage or the raw data.

Say one tile contains $.25 \text{km}^2$ of buildings.  Then the percentage covering is $25\%$.  In general if the raw data is $X$ then the percentage is just is $100X$.  In effect all this does is scale the standard deviation.  You will find that if the standard deviation of the raw data (in those units) is $\sigma$, then the standard deviation of the percentage is $100\sigma$.  Then how you symbolize these deviations can just take into account the difference in scaling.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the quick response.

Comment: .Happy to help.